# assigning the result of variable into textblock

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get the result of variable into a textblock.text proprety, I'm using 
this code:

`bool isavailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

result = isavailable.ToString();`

```
<TextBlock Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0"  
           Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding  result}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="400" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" />`
```

Comment: i forgot to add this code:<TextBlock Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding  result}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to keep the binding? The *simplest* approach here would be to simply use:

```
textBlock1.Text = result;
```

However, the *better* approach would be to use a ViewModel implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` with an appropriate property. Then you would make your `TextBlock` bind to the property, and set the property from your code. The property would raise the appropriate event, and the UI would update accordingly.